# Incorrect focus the Visibility binding property changes dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, setfocus

In a UserControl, I've got a bunch of Labels and TextBoxes within a Grid:

examples of labels:

```
<Label
    Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
    Uid="TrainDetails"
    Content="{lex:Loc}"
    Style="{DynamicResource H2Label}"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    Visibility="{Binding DisplayDestinationSearch, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverterHiddenWhenTrue}}"
    Margin="20"/>

<Label
    Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"
    Uid="DestinationSearch"
    Content="{lex:Loc}"
    Style="{DynamicResource H2Label}"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    Visibility="{Binding DisplayDestinationSearch, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverterHiddenWhenFalse}}"
    Margin="20"/>
```

When the `DisplayDestinationSearch` property is set to true dynamically in code, the labels, hide/display as expected however, the grid somehow gets focus - there's a faint grid around it.

Using Snoop, this shows the focus element is `ContentControl`. if I press the tab key on my keyboard, it switches between all the text boxes as expected.

How can I avoid the grid getting focus and let one of the textboxes have focus instead?

I've tried adding `IsTabStop="True"` to the TextBoxes and `Focusable="False"` to the Grid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Focusable for the parent `ContentControl`. Focusable is derived from parent and hence is set to true (default)

```
<ContentControl Focusable="False" />
```

Comment: on content control ? if other things being usual, focus should not be set on grid considering both content control and grid are set to no focus

Comment: The focus isn't on the grid when the control (a dialog popup) loads. The grid gets focus when a property (which is associated to a visibility binding) changes. However, I want focus to be on a textbox that becomes visible.